# Live scan tool for OBD 1.5 GM transitional?

Tags: obd-ii, gm, electronic-control-module, obd-i, s10

**1995 S-10 Blazer 4.3L Vortec V6 (vin W) with Powertrain Control Module (PCM)**

1995 was the OBD transitional year for GM.  The PCM itself is OBDI, but the interface connector has the 16-pin D-style OBDII plug.  Therefore, most inexpensive OBDII scan tools cannot establish a connection to this vehicle's computer although it plugs in.  Some OBDI scan tools will also not work with this vehicle since the interface connector is not OBDII style.  For example, the Craftsman model 20899 is for OBDI and OBDII but specifically excludes all 1995 S/T series vehicles even though the connector is compatible.

I can easily extract the codes via a jumper and reading the MIL light flashes.  However, I'd really like to get a tool for live scanning.

Does anyone have a comprehensive list of live scan tool brands/models that will work with my car?  Some need a special interface cable accessory that's not included, so this information is also requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Actron CP9145 that reads obd 1.5 on my 1995 GMC Jimmy. does not read ABS or Airbag though. Bought it new for $135 a couple of years ago. Don't remember if I got it on Ebay or Amazon. I know this is an old thread but I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 95 Chev Astro 4.3 Vortec V6 with the transitionary OBD1.5 connector and I use a Craftsman Scantool CanOBD2&1 Kit, part number 920899 (about $300+ US back around the turn of the century [2000]), to read the codes and reset faults. It works. It has always worked. I bought it to talk to my '86 and '88 OBDI TransAM WS6 GTAs which it does quite well. I had no idea what OBD1.5 was until I bought my 95 Explorer Conversion Van but I guess I lucked out because it has saved me countless hours of diagnostic time tracking down weird problems like a leaking injector hose (inside the bread loaf upper intake manifold). I found my way here looking to see if anyone had found a way to interface an OBD2 reader to this connector since it gives out OBD2 data but the connector doesn't match up. I figured I'd make a quick check to see if there was already something out here before I tried my hand at building an adapter. I want to interface an OBD2 bluetooth adapter to send real time data to my Nexus 7 tablet like I do with my 97 Ford Ranger. ;-)

Comment: Thank-you for posting an answer.  My friend has the same one and it did not work on my car.  The owner's manual on this Craftsman scanner specifically *excludes* my year/make/model.

Comment: I just purchased a Craftsman 09.20899 because of above post saying it will work on 95 chev 16pin. It does not work on 94 Park Avenue and the manual says it will not work on 94 and 95 16pin vehicles. I have to conclude that this tool does NOT work on OBD 1.5 protocol. Anyone need a Craftsman 09.20899???

Comment: The post does not say it will work on a 95 Chevy 16-pin (mine is '95 Chevy Blazer w/ 16-pin and does not work).  Dr Dav's post simply says it works on his '95 Chevy Astro.  You have to check the Craftsman manual for the list of makes & models supported.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, if you had OBD 1.5, you wouldn't be able to use the jumper method. I could be wrong, but my '94 Bonneville will not work with it. Does it have a 12-pin or 16-pin OBD port? If it's a 16 and you can pull codes via a jumper, you probably do have OBD 1.5 (GM is a pain isn't it).

The guys at Pontiac Bonneville Club claim an Action CP9110 will work, but its difficult to get a hold of one as they're no longer being made. This link does reference a method to make a CP9115 cable which I'm assuming is also difficult to find, but helpful should you find the tool: http://www.pontiacbonnevilleclub.com/forum/1992/topic199.html

If you can find one (or afford one for that matter) you may have luck with a Tech 1 or Tech 2, GMs proprietary automotive tech tool.

I frequent the Bonneville site and am currently working with a gentleman on getting my hands on a Bonneville datastream file (.DS) and editing necessary aspects so as to fit my car and then using a 16-pin OBD to USB cable (purchased on reddevilriver.com, a site I do not own) along with EFILive v4.

Good luck.

Comment: I really have no idea if I have OBDI or OBD1.5... all I can tell you is that I **can** retrieve codes with the jumper and I have an OBDII style connector (16-pin D-style).  I also know that OBDII scan tools will not work.  I'll check into your suggestions above.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have the OBD 2 connector but can pull OBD 1 codes via a jumper, pray to the GM gods for being so lucky. As I said, OBD 1.5 scanning tools are virtually nonexistent. They're out there, but they're already owned and/or no longer for sale. I've done **copious** research into pulling those codes and I've come with nothing but having a knack for soldering and using PC based automotive software. The OBD 2 requirement really has forsaken a few of us, myself included.

Comment: Like I said, I have an OBDI computer with an OBDII 16-pin interface... not really sure on the 1.5.   However, what you're saying does not really make a lot of sense to me.  My neighbor is a mechanic and has **two** different scan tools that have been successfully used on my car... the better one is a Genisys and the other is an Auto X-ray.  I simply thought I'd ask the question here so I could have several more options when shopping for used units on eBay.